# How to copy a row 50 times and insert in same table with a autoincrement id field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I am trying to copy a row with an autoincrement column ID=k and insert in the same table as a new row.
let suppose there are 10 rows in the table, so after the executing query there will be 500 rows in the table.

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: it would be great if you can write answer for both, MySQL and SQL Server as well

Comment: not sure about the version, you can assume the latest one

Comment: @RahulKumar: `select version()` can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate numbers and then insert based on that:

```
insert into t ( . . . ) -- all columns besides the auto increment column
    with recursive cte as (
          select 1 as n
          union all
          select n + 1
          from cte
          where n < 49
         )
    select . . . -- all columns but the auto increment column
    from t cross join
         cte;
```

The "49" can be dynamic if you want to end up with 500 rows.  The above inserts the existing rows an additional 49 times.

Comment: can you mention the full form of cte?

Comment: @RahulKumar . . . I don't understand your comment.  The CTE *is* complete.

Comment: i think its common table expresion

Comment: @RahulKumar . . . Yes.  CTE standard for "common table expression".  That would more simply be known as "that which is defined with `with`".

Comment: using insert before CTE and later use select does not work as you explained in above anser., i run sample db on https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql and https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/

Comment: @RahulKumar . . . This code works in MySQL (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43a7c7c6ae5f708b8a12974d126eb259).  Your first link does not have the code.  The second is using SQLite.